# numpy.loadtxt, ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: numpy

This is sample from large csv file:

```
6.1;6.1;7.2;8.9;5.0;
8.9;10.0;8.9;6.1;5.0;
```

If I try to read it to numpy array with `np.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter=';')` I get:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

and don't understand why?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to strip off the trailing `';'` from the lines.

A possible workaround if you know you have 5 columns is:

```
np.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter=';', usecols=range(5))
```

Or, use `genfromtext` instead which handles missing values

```
np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=';')[:,:-1]
```

Comment: You are right, but I can't strip trailing `;` for some lines as there are missing values. Using `usecols=range(5)` if line ends with `;;` (i.e. last value is missing) yields to error again

Comment: Maybe I should use other module to read CSV. I tried `pandas` right now, and it reads just fine as anyone would have expected, but OTOH I don't want to load huge package just to read CSV to array, and don't use it again...

Comment: Nah I think numpy is a good choice, there is `csv` module but it's more for strings ..

Comment: I just got a tip to use `np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=';')` instead - works like a charm. I must have overlooked your last line

Comment: Under Windows I have problem with no-ANSI encoded files

Answer (score 18):

So in my case the csv file had column names written in the first row. e.g.

```
Column1,Column2,Column3
5.4,2.3,2.4
6.7,3.6,9.3
```

So as given in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), all I had to do was use the *skiprows* parameter

So the API call became,

`np.loadtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)`