# Python. NumPy File I/O. Sorting. Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, csv, numpy

I'm trying to read values from a CSV file, but I'm getting an error.

Here is code snippet:

```
import numpy as np

file_read=np.loadtxt('stock_px.csv', delimiter=',')
print ("Restored data: \n" + str(file_read))
```

Here is error message:

```
  ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: What is the content of 'stock_px.csv'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy.loadtxt, ValueError: could not convert string to float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729210/numpy-loadtxt-valueerror-could-not-convert-string-to-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the documentation for `np.loadtxt` and type `help(np.loadtxt)` into your interpreter.

It has an optional `dtype` argument which is the data type that it tries to turn the data into. By default this is float. There are strings in your csv which `np.loadtxt` is unable to interpret as floats. If it's all strings you can set `dtype=str` instead.